# Navbar links die in Bootstrap 4 until page reload - Rails 5 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I just moved over to Bootstrap 4 and noticed some weird behavior in my app.  All of the navbar links work fine on the first try, including the dropdowns, but after the linked page loads, all of the navbar links are dead.  They come alive again when I reload whatever page I happen to be on.

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color:white">
    ... some content
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        ...
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         ...
      </li>     
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is this a known issue with Bootstrap 4, or am I seeing something else?

Comment: Doesn't sound related to BS4. Make sure you've installed popper.js and there are no JS errors in the browser

Comment: Yeah, I've got popper.js and checked the console for errors - there are none.  But I will recheck.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

When I posted my original question, I didn't specify that this was a Rails 5 application.

Originally, I had tried to load bootstrap using the CDN links provided at the bootstrap site:

```
<head>

  ...

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

  ...

</head>

<body>

  ...


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  ...

</body>
```

I wrestled with this for some time and couldn't solve the problem.  It seemed that none of my javascript-related bootstrap components (e.g. popovers) worked unless I reloaded the page.

In the end, I gutted all of this and opted for the bootstrap-ruby gem.  When I followed the implementation instructions, everything worked fine.

I'd still be interested in knowing why the CDN solution didn't work.